# look for json key's value in jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jpa, predicates

i am using criteriabuilder of jpa and i want to look for a value of a json field in a jsonb column.
the jsonb looks like this :

```
[{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"},{"field3":"value3","field4":"value4"}]
```

i started creating my predicates but i got errors.

```
predicates.add( builder.like(
    builder.function("JSON_EXTRACT", String.class, root1.get("jsonBColumn"),                          
    builder.literal("\"value3\"")), "%" + searchValue + "%"));
```

the error i am getting is

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function json_extract(jsonb,
>   character varying) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given
>   name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Can anybody help ?

Comment: Here's an idea. Format your post so that it is half readable ...

Comment: ok i did format my post

Comment: And did you read the error message? "json_extract" doesn't exist, from your database. So perhaps, just perhaps there is no such function with that name. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

`predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.like(cb.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", String.class, root.get("jsonBColumn"), cb.literal(this.searchKey)), "%"+ this.searchValue + "%"));